# How do I query with multiple orderby in same column?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a list of posts, one column of which I am trying to set in alphabetical order. The problem is that these posts have one of two different value types shown in the same column.

The code I have tried below gets me halfway there, it does query the posts with one of those values at the top but still not in alphabetical order.

```
$posts_per_page = 10;
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'offerter',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_key' => 'business_id',
    'meta_value' => $business_id,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        'customer_name' => array(
            'key' => 'customer_name',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        'quick_customer_name' => array(
            'key' => 'quick_customer_name',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
        'customer_name' => 'desc',
        'quick_customer_name' => 'desc',
    )
```

I have tried to compare EXISTS and LIKE, which sort of gets me the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use at last of of your query
eg:

```
$collection = new Collection($put_your_array_here);

// Paginate
$perPage = 10; // Item per page
$currentPage = Input::get('page') - 1; // url.com/test?page=2
$pagedData = $collection->slice($currentPage * $perPage, $perPage)->all();
$collection= Paginator::make($pagedData, count($collection), $perPage)->orderby('customer_name' => 'desc')->orderby('customer_name' => 'desc');
```

Comment: Thanks - not working though, just getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by creating a 3rd custom field and a function to save either the ´customer_name´ or ´quick_customer_name´ to the new field. Then do a orderby on that third field.